# The tag tooltip only shows in preview of edit mode, and not in live

Tags: bug, tags, design, tooltips

If you use `[tag:tag]` (e.g. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)), the system will show the tooltip in edit mode. But in live the system doesn't show it.

> [image]

This applies to both the inline editor and the separate edit page (`/posts/[post-id]/edit`).

Comment: To be clear: tooltip is showen, but it’s differ, i.e. only the raw string instead of tag description block.