# Suggested tags are not displayed with their excerpts and other info when asking/editing a question on mobile

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, responsive-design, popups

When asking or editing a question, one is offered tag suggestions while typing in the "Tags" section. On a desktop browser, each popup also displays the tag wiki excerpt (when available), its usage count, a help icon that links to the tag info page, and any attached synonyms.

However, when I was suggesting an edit on a post on my mobile browser today, I noticed that the tag popups only show the tag name, without any of the other information that is seen on a desktop browser.

This is what I'm seeing when trying to ask a question on Meta SE on a phone:

[image: Screenshot of the new view on mobile.]

In my opinion, this makes it more difficult to select the right tags when these helpful details are not present. Can the tag excerpts and other info also be displayed on mobile (i.e., small screen) devices?

Comment: Note: This doesn't seem to be a "responsive design" problem, since my desktop browser when narrow doesn't have an issue with this. It's only my iPhone (even in landscape mode).

Comment: @Laurel, I wonder how it could be a good way to add details about the devices used for testing / focus the dev efforts. Should the community add an answer for each type of device and browser combination with a real user base daily (not literally daily) using it? I mean, it hasn't any value to make a list of devices and browsers then make a combination and run tests if no real users are using this feature, on the other hand, iPhone is a very popular device, but what browser is used by SE power users using iPhones? Safari? Chrome? Firefox? Are there stats about this available for the community?

Comment: @Rubén I often edit info on what setup I reproduced the issue on into other people's questions directly. I wouldn't hesitate to do that for any setup that's officially supported by SE.

Comment: Related [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/289691)

Comment: The Amplitwist: The tag excerpt of [tag:mobile] says "DO NOT USE". Considering this,  please add more details like the name and version of the operative system and web browser used. On the other hand, is this issue still happening to you in November 2023?

Comment: Further testing tells me that this doesn't seem to be platform-specific (whoops). However, you have to load the Ask Question (or edit) page in narrow mode for it to happen. It doesn't happen when I load the page in landscape mode and switch to portrait.

Comment: @Rubén sorry but can't see how adding the related tags improve the feature request. Also, this is not limited to mobile devices or phones, it happens with any small screen. Resize the screen even in desktop PC and you'll see this behavior happening. It's just a bad choice by the developers in the way responsive design is implemented, so this feature request is asking to change this.

Comment: @Laurel maybe you didn't reload after resizing? I [do see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjOVS.png) when resizing the screen, using a desktop PC.

Comment: Also, on second thought, since this behavior cause useful feature to be missing (showing tag info), might can be considered a bug, so added the [tag:bug] tag, if and when staff will review/fix it, they can remove one of the tags, as they see fit.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry No problem. Thanks for the feedback. The [tag:feature-request] + [tag:bug] approach looks good to me.

Comment: Is this related [Display Tag Excerpt tooltips when editing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168035/289691)?  [tag:feature-request] + [tag:status-review]

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry If you load the page in wide mode, resize to narrow, and then refresh, yes, this bug will be triggered. (Because refreshing will load the page when you're in narrow mode.)

Comment: @Laurel indeed, the responsive design isn't "live", it's rendering upon loading. (At least some aspects of it, e.g. the missing elements which are removed to save space for what the designers deem important.)

Answer (score -3):

I was able to reproduce this. Per [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) guidance:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Screensize (in) | 6.8 |
| Screensize (pixels) | 2340 x 1080 pixels |
| Zooming | 80 % |
| OS | Android 10 |
| Browser | Chrome version 119 |

---

This question might not have yet reached the attention that it might "need" despite the content and the missing details that it might have.

| Mandatory Tag | Remark |
| --- | --- |
| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | Originally was tagged as feature request |
| [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) | This was tagged as a bug as it's unclear if there is a problem that should be escalated as a bug instead of a new feature or change request. |

## Related Feature Requests

| [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) | Mod Only Tag |
| --- | --- |
| [Display Tag Excerpt tooltips when editing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168035/) | [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) |

## Related tags

The [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) (<-- [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile)) tag excerpt says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR NEW QUESTIONS UNLESS THEY ARE ABOUT CHAT! Use in combination with [chat] for posts about the mobile versions of the chat sites. The mobile views of the main sites have been removed.

| Tag "Category" or "Family" | Tags | Related |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mobile Operative Systems / Devices | [android](/questions/tagged/android), [ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad), [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [mobile-device](/questions/tagged/mobile-device) |  |
| Mobile Web Browsers | [mobile-chrome](/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome),[mobile-firefox](/questions/tagged/mobile-firefox),[mobile-safari](/questions/tagged/mobile-safari), [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) |  |
| "Product" | [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) |  |
| Design | [design](/questions/tagged/design), [popup](/questions/tagged/popup), [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) | [How to get hover information on mobile, e.g. details of a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369722/) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [The tag tooltip only shows in preview of edit mode, and not in live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315827/) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) |

## Relevance

##### Showing the Tag Excerpt while Editing Tags on Mobile

As I mentioned in the bounty notice, some users have completely stopped using laptops and computers. Whether this should be raised first to the Community Team by the local moderators, and later to the developer team / higher management is unclear.

While there might be very few Meta Stack Exchange users in this situation, using only phones, many Stack Exchange users probably are. AFAIK, the community hasn't access to analytics about the device type used to access Stack Exchange sites. Because of this, those concerned about the user experience and service level have to rely on hints directly given by the *community*.

I will look for a way to collect those hints. I will keep you posted on the chatroom I created last weekend, which I mentioned but have not linked to yet, in my previous question.

This "awakening" is derived from some stats I read a few days ago, mentioning that most **Facebook**'s worldwide users use only their phones to access Facebook services. I think that it's reasonable to infer that the same might happen in other similar businesses motivated, as Facebook and Google, by trends to invest or derived from investments in Information Technology and Communication like [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing). I understand that the most critical thinkers might criticize just mentioning Facebook and Google.

The "phone only" user base should not be overseen, starting by myself. Later, I might make a specific post to support this claim if I find evidence and the proper conditions for doing something like that. I.E., the intended writing be of interest to this community instead of being of interest only to me.